# iOS AWS S3 Transfer Utility not uploading

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transferutility

I've implemented [this](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx283AGGIL76PKP/Amazon-S3-Transfer-Utility-for-iOS) tutorial exactly, and i'm able to successfully upload an image to a s3 bucket using the uploadData method (the completion handler block runs with error=nil). My problem is that  I can't see the file in the bucket when i'm looking through the AWS console, so I'm not sure if the image was uploaded successfully and due to wrong permissions or something like that I can't find it or if the image was not really uploaded.

Any idea what's wrong ?

Edit -

I've added permissions to the S3 bucket in the role policy of the new Cognito pool id that I've created for the client authentication purposes, but still no help.

Edit 2 - 
I've also opened permissions on the bucket itself to everyone.

Comment: Make sure your bucket was created in the same region as your Cognito pool ids...

Comment: @goldengil, That was it. If you would add this as an answer i'll accept it..

Comment: btw, I ended up using the TransferManager because i couldn't find how to set the ACL of the uploaded image to public using the Transfer Utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your bucket was created in the same region as your Cognito pool ids.